# How can copy and rename file in 1 time?

Tags: copy, rename

How can i copy and rename a file like this.

From 'C:\Data\123456789_Sheet.dwg' to 'D:\Data\123456789.dwg'

Thanks

Comment: Is this from the command line? What OS or terminal are you using? Is this PowerShell, Bash, Zsh? Or are you doing this programmatically using a language like Java or Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

It's a task i should do in Win 10.

I just put the code in notepad en execute it with task scheduler.